# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
print ("Hello World")
print ("{} World").format(Hello)
```

I'm working on my first "Hello World" program and I can get it to work by using the print function and just a simple string text but when I try to use `.format` it gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Is this saying that I need to initialize a variable for `.format` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 47):

Your brackets are wrong

```
print("Hello World")
print("{} World".format('Hello'))
```

Note -  the errors

- The `format` function is an attribute of `str` so it needs to be called on the string
- Unless declared, `Hello` is a string and should be `'Hello'`

For Py2 you can do

```
print "{} World".format('Hello')
```

Comment: I don't think so. It should work even with the parantheses. Just tested it on Python 2.64. Normally, parantheses used in this fashion (i.e. not a tuple), simply evaluate what's inside and would behave exactly the same way in a situation like this. i.e. `("{0} World").format('Hello')` _is_ the same as `("{} World".format('Hello'))`

Comment: @Eithos This is Python 3.4

Comment: Oh. Right. _Print_ is now a function in 3.x. My bad.

Comment: This helped me as I had mismatching brackets. Is there a way to have Python check for errors like this, like a compiler would?

Comment: Nope, @Celeritas. However isn't it very easy to discover such errors? After a few hours of coding for python, we all might discover such errors a bit faster. Anyway, I will search around if there are any tools that can aid in such errors (Though I cannot guarantee to find one). Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Function `print` returns `None`, so that's obviously what you're getting from the start of your second statement, namely

```
print ("{} World")
```

On that return value of `None`, you then call `.format(Hello)` -- even if a variable named `Hello` was assigned somewhere in your code (and you're not showing it to us!), you're calling that `.format` method on the `None` returned from your `print` call, which makes no sense.

Rather, you want to call `.format` on the **string** `"{} World"` -- so the closed-paren right after the string and before the dot is clearly a terrible mistake!  Move that `)` to the end of the statement, **after** the call to `format` on that string.

Moreover, **is** `Hello` the name of a variable whose value you want to format?  I sure hope not, else why haven't you shown us that variable being assigned?!  I suspect you want to format a **constant string** and just absent-mindedly forgot to **put it in quotes** (to show it's a constant, not the name of a variable!) -- `'Hello'`, **not** `Hello` without quotes!  *That* is what you should be passing to the proper form of the `.format` call...!

Answer (score 0):

even thought the requestor of the original question was wrong in using the `.format` structure - I believe he's still right about one thing - the behavior in Python3 is different when having a value that equals `None`

Example

```
fmt = '{:^9}|{:^13}|{:^18}'
data = [1, None, 'test']

print(fmt.format(*data))
```

Python2.7

```
$ python2.7 test
    1    |    None     |       test
```

In Python3.6

```
python3.6 test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test", line 5, in <module>
    print(fmt.format(*data))
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__
```

But if we remove the `format`'s features of column-width

```
fmt = '{}|{}|{}'
data = [1, None, 'test']

print(fmt.format(*data))
```

OR convert all values to Strings using `!s`

```
fmt = '{!s:^9}|{!s:^13}|{!s:^18}'
```

It works just fine in both versions ...