# Python 3.5.2 .format()

Tags: python-3.x, format

I just started to learn python and I cant figure out how to use .format, I get a syntax problem every time I try it. Here's the code.

```
my_name = input("What is your name:")
my_age = input("What is your age:")
print ("So you are {name} and you are{age}")format(name=my_name,age=my_age)
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: You should call `.format` on a string, not the result of `print()`. `print ("So you are {name} and you are{age}".format(name=my_name,age=my_age))`

Comment: Also you're missing the `.`, despite including it in the title.

Comment: This is cause by a simple typo error for `format`. There is no dot.

Comment: @MoonCheesez it's both, changing one or the other won't fix it alone.

Comment: Half of the problem is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/28378257/3001761. The other half is a trivial typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`format` is a method of `str` so you should call that from your string, then pass the result of that into `print`.

```
print ("So you are {name} and you are{age}".format(name=my_name,age=my_age))
```